# Delphi Rest.JSON serialisation and TCriticalSection object in RAD Studio XE5

Tags: json, rest, delphi

In my class I have a TCriticalSection object, which has to be declared from within the object itself.

When I try to serialise / deserialise using the class REST.JSon, I get the error: Type TKPointer is not currently supported.

Tried to use both attributes:

```
[JSONMarshalledAttribute(False)] (this one should be appropriate with REST.JSon)
[JSONMarshalled(False)]
```

This is declaration snipplet:

```
[JSONMarshalledAttribute(False)]
FCriticalSection: TCriticalSection;
```

but with no success as the property is still serialised in JSon.

I understand JSon cannot serialise Pointers, but **I can't avoid the use of TCriticalSection object as it's running in a Thread and it has to be declared from within the class interface**.

> I found a workaround by setting the object to nil before serialising the class
>   so I get the following JSon:
>
> ```
> {"criticalSection":null}
> ```
>
> It's dirty coding and would like to sort it out more appropriately, even because when I read the class back I have to reinstantiate the object itself.

Appreciate.

Comment: JSONMarshalled attribute is also declared in `REST.Json.Types`.  You should use that unit (and not `Data.DBXJSONReflect` if that's what you're using).  Otherwise show how you're serializing/deserializing and your full class declaration

Comment: Thanks Jason, I already tried to use REST.Json.Types but I can't find it in my environment (I'm using Rad Studio XE5). [dcc32 Fatal Error] Unit6.pas(9): F1026 File not found: 'REST.Json.Types.dcu'

Comment: "*I'm using Rad Studio XE5*" - that is the kind of information you need to provide up front. The `REST.Json.Types` unit and JSON serialization attributes were introduced in XE6 (as part of the new JSON serialization support for FireDAC. See [What's New in Delphi and C++Builder XE6](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE6)).